# Какой индекс поставить в таблицу innodb mysql?

Tags: mysql, innodb, индексы

Есть большая таблица больше 10 гигобайт, есть запрос такого типа

```
SELECT * from humans WHERE `lastname_id` = '223' AND `firstname_id` = '72' ORDER BY `rate` DESC LIMIT 10 OFFSET 10
```

Какой индекс необходимо поставить для максимального быстродействия?
Сейчас стоит на lastname_id, firstname_id и rate а также составной на всех этих трех полях.
Таблица innodb.
Когда проверяю через explain то вижу, что используются отдельные индексы lastname_id и firstname_id, а составной индекс (у меня он называется lastname_id_2) не используется.
[image: explain]
И данная картинка не есть хорошо... Почему не используется составной индекс?
Скрин индексов:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В каком именно порядке указаны поля в составном индексе?

Comment: В перечисленном порядке: lastname_id, firstname_id, rate. Добавил скрин индексов в вопрос.

Comment: Попробуйте использовать подсказки оптимизатора https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/index-hints.html  и никогда не заключайте в кавычки значения для числовых полей, еще не известно как он решит привести типы и как это скажется на оптимизаторе.  Вообще кажется, что составной индекс будет лучшим выбором. Почему он вообще использует firstname не ясно, его селективность просто никакая. Я бы индекс на это поле вообще бы удалил, но я так понимаю он у вас используется для обеспечения внешнего ключа, так что его нельзя удалять :(